# mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string] is preventing server connection

Tags: php, mysql-real-escape-string

Can someone explain why am getting this error when am setting up a new website? and how to solve it

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/sitename/public_html/cms/cms/admin/report.php on line 8
```

Now contents of line 8:

```
$report = mysql_real_escape_string( $report );
```

**EDIT**

```
<?php

require_once('auth.php'); require('core/plugin.php');
// session details  are here 
require('core/connection.php');
if($session_id == $session_id){
    $report = $_POST['reportmsg'];
    $report = strip_tags( $report );
    $report = mysql_real_escape_string( $report );
    $report = trim( $report );
    if($report == ""){
        die("textarea void");
        exit();
    } elseif($report == $report) {
        $sql="INSERT INTO report (site_id, date, time, ticket_id, bug)
        VALUES
        ( 
            '$session_id',
            '$date',
            '$time',
            '$ticket_id',
            '$report'
        )";
        if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
            die("Failed  to connect");
            exit();
        }
        echo ("<font style='font-family:Tahoma;'>ticket sent</font>");
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: it's line 8 if I still able to count.

Comment: Ya line 8 has the problem but why? and how to solve it

Comment: "U" have said it's line 14. You need to sort out your code first.

Comment: other code have been remoded where i wrote session details are here. the question has been edited

Comment: Instead of messing with all the SQL escaping, please use parametrized queries, and maybe even switch to PDO, to avoid your SQL injections.  See http://bobby-tables.com/php for examples.

Comment: @AndyLester Turns out he's already using mysqli, he's just using the wrong escaping function.

Comment: I know he's using mysqli.  Please reread what I wrote: "Instead of messing with all the SQL escaping, please use parametrized queries..."

Comment: @AndyLester Sorry if I misunderstood, I read your comment as saying he needs to switch to PDO to avoid SQL injections, so assumed you didn't notice he was using `mysqli` (which has [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)) rather than `mysql`.

Comment: thanks to @AndyLester i ll try that in next vision it show to be good suggestion

Comment: @codefun Have added a little on bound statements in `mysqli` to my answer, the documentation is very clear and will help you a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You haven't established a connection to your database

This function takes into account the character set on the database you're using ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)), so it needs a connection to a database in order to work. Run this **before** any escape strings:

```
mysql_connect('server','username','password');
```

Or alternatively, consider not using `mysql_*` because it's deprecated, may fall out of maintenance and may be removed from a future version of PHP. You may be better off using [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

**Edit: Looks like you may already be using `mysqli`**

Since you added your code, I noticed that your query is called with `mysqli_query`. You are probably connected to your database using `mysqli`, in which case, change the following line:

```
mysql_real_escape_string($report);
```

To this line:

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$report);
```

These are two different APIs and don't share connection objects, so your `mysql_*` function cannot use your `mysqli_*` connection.

**Having said that, you may be better off using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)...**

Lines and lines of escaping can make your queries safe, but they're expensive and introduce [boilerplate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code) into your code.

As others have suggested, you may wish to look into prepared statements instead:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO `report` (site_id, date, time, ticket_id, bug) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "issis", $session_id, $date, $time, $ticket_id, $report);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

**On a side note, re: `die()` and `exit()`**

You use this a few times in your code:

```
die("textarea void");
exit();
```

These two functions are aliases (`die()` and `exit()` do exactly the same thing), and your code never reaches `exit()`. You can drop the `exit();` statements where they occur after `die();`

Comment: am connected to server in the same way you suggest, other information from server is been seen(fetched) before i get the error that's why i was wondering whats the problem

Comment: @codefun You probably need to show more of your code for us to be able to diagnose the issue. I'd suggest that as you seem to be in early stages of your code, you're best off dropping the deprecated library in favour of `mysqli` (which is easier too).

Comment: @codefun Out of interest, what happens if you pass the connection identifier to the `mysql_real_escape_string` explicitly? `$connection = mysql_connect('server','username','password'); mysql_real_escape_string($report, $connection);`

Comment: @codefun If your problem is with the network rather than the program, you'll need to make a new question (and might be one for Serverfault rather than SO).

Comment: i mean internet connect that's why i reply late

Comment: @codefun I need to see `core/connection.php`. It looks like you're using `mysqli` for your query, which means you've probably connected via `mysqli` rather than `mysql` (these are two different drivers). Try changing `mysql_real_escape_string` to `mysqli_real_escape_string` ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) -- there is a difference in syntax).

Comment: '<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","wings","password","communities"); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){ echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); } 
?>'

Comment: @codefun Have updated my answer. Issue is you're using two different database drivers.

Comment: Thanks for adding the die suggestion i lent... end your code works. i appreciate

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

```
A MySQL connection is required before using mysql_real_escape_string() otherwise an error of level E_WARNING is generated, and FALSE is returned. If link_identifier isn't defined, the last MySQL connection is used.
```

therefore, I bet that you're not connected to your database.

Answer (score 0):

**Do not use this function at all**. At least directly in the application code. **Prepared statements** ought to be used instead. This is the only proper solution.

As to why you are getting this error, [a manual page](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) usually have an explanation for the every error you get with particular function.